# url rewriting - rewriting image path to internal folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to add a rule to redirect jpg files to a directory beyond the document root. I already use the following which rewrites anything without a file extension.

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^.]+$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I want to achieve

`http://www.mysite.com/i/image_type/12345.jpg`

`=>`


`/internal_path/image_type/12345.jpg`

EDIT In this case I ended up using a symbolic link. I am not sure if it was the best solution but it served my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

For your image path, use this rule (put it at the end of your `.htaccess`) :

```
RewriteRule ^i/(.*)$ /internal_path/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check this:

```
RewriteRule ^i/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)\.([a-z0-9-_]+)$ /internal_path/$1/$2.$3
```